# I Can´t get INSERT to work

Tags: php, mysql

I have been banging my head to the wall with this:

1. get the POST values to array..
2. Select the foreign key..
3. Some other INSERT-operations

```
$insertdates = "INSERT INTO dates (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate
               , maintenance_period, expiration_date) 
               VALUES ('$foreignkey','$uservalues[1]'
               ,'$uservalues[4]','$uservalues[5]','$uservalues[3]')";
$upsdasult= mysql_query($insertdates);
```

All the values are in the correct format before the insert and $foreignkey is in correct format.
*(I have echoed the values before the insert statement)*.
The operation runs succesfully, but when I look at the database, nothing has been inserted.

Could Somebody please tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: echo the full sql query and put the result on a phpmyadmin SQL box

Comment: Have you echo the query and paste it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Is there any primary key in table?

Comment: Thanks everyone, but still no luck...
This is what I get when I echo the query:

    INSERT INTO dates (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate, maintenance_period, expiration_date) VALUES ('47','2008-01-29','2050-03-07','34','2069-12-22')

So it seems that the values are ok, but still nothing appears in the table. 

Any ideas?

Comment: SHow your php code where the mysql_error is called. kr

Comment: Can you please post the entire php ststement from sql to the mysql_query... it seems like you are doing this mysql_error($sql) instead of mysql_query($sql)

Comment: I am forcing the values to be INT                              $pickassssult=(int)$pickassssult;
$uservalues[5]=(int)$uservalues[5]; And yes this is actually the same question, but this page does not allow new users to add a new question to the thread in 8 hours

Comment: you should check the value of mysql_error()

Answer (score 3):

You have to use curly braces to embed a array variable:

```
echo "This is an {$array['value']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    $insertdates = "INSERT INTO dates (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate, 
    maintenance_period, expiration_date) 
    VALUES ('".$foreignkey."','".$uservalues['1']."','".$uservalues['4'].
    "','".$uservalues['5']."','".$uservalues['3']."')";
    $upsdasult= mysql_query($insertdates);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
$insertdates = "INSERT INTO dates (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate
  , maintenance_period, expiration_date) 
  VALUES ('$foreignkey','$uservalues[1]','$uservalues[4]'
  ,'$uservalues[5]','$uservalues[3]')";
$upsdasult= mysql_query($insertdates);
if (!$upsdasult)
{
  die(mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n");
}
```

Chances are it doesn't like either the key, or a date format, but this will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your $_POST values
2. try this query :

   ```
   $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO dates set 

                        asid = '%s',
                        acq_date = '%s',
                        serv_guaranteedate = '%s',
                        maintenance_period = '%s',
                        expiration_date = '%s'",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($foreignkey),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($uservalues[1]),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($uservalues[4]),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($uservalues[5]),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($uservalues[3])
                    );
   ```

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   ```
   if($result) { echo 'success'; } else { echo mysql_error(); }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Leave mysql_error() empty..... use the below code....

```
$upsdasult= mysql_query($insertdates) or die(mysql_error());
```

You dont need the rest of the code....

I think you have copied the same query from this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php. But mysql_error will anyway print the error code for you....

Please try this and let me know if this is what you are looking for....

Comment: No the error code is irrelevant. What I want to know is why is the $pickassssult (foreignkey) value disappering. I can echo my query and i see it and I have made sure that it is in INT-format, but it disappers when the quety is actually run.

Comment: @Henkka you say `asid` is a foreignkey... and you are trying to insert value 47 in that field.... have you checked whether the primary key 47 exist in your other related table? because if the field is foreign key it would not accept any other value other than the primary key of the related table... even NULL is not acceptable if the field is set not null...

Comment: yes, primary key 47 exists and I have picked it to the for the $pickassssult (foreign key) integer, so I can use it later on and I can see it with the echo command. The problem is that the value 47 seems to disappears when the actual query is run. Also the field does not accept NULL values and is restrained with CASCADE Commands

Comment: @Henkka did you tried copying the output query directly in to your mysql... is that inserting correctly? sorry i am just trying to debug...

Comment: I am not trying to be rude. I am just trying to give you enough information so you could help, because I am baffled... yes the output generated with the echo command is the actual query tha i am running and the values are the values which should populate the table in question. But from what I understand the value 47 never goes to the DB, even when it shows on the screen

Comment: @Henkka no my question is whether you tried running the printed query directly on to the phpmyadmin or mysql query browser? If it is not insearting then you got your relationship wrong.....

Comment: oh, yes I can run it directly to mysql query browser and there is no problem. All the tables and fields populate correctly when running it from command prompt.

Comment: i know what it is now.... DO NOT INCLUDE '' single quots around the int statement... I think it is trying it as an string and have problem insearting it to the foreign key field... eventhough I know mysql will accept '' quoted in int its jut a try... Please dont mind...

Comment: Did not work, still the same error, but it runs both ways (with and without '') from command promt and the result is what it is supposed to be, but no difference when running from PHP-side. I get more stuff in some tables (which don't use it as foreignkey) but still it won't populate the tables where IT IS used as foreign key

Answer (score -1):

Is it not the case that your FK value should be an integer rather than a string? How about if you don't use `'$foreignkey'` but only use instead `$foreignkey` ?

Comment: -1 Using `$foreignkey` instead of `'$foreignkey'` opens up a SQL-injection hole.

Comment: it does anyway -- one can set foreignkey="' drop table..." (so close the apostrophe inside the value. secondly if he sets the foreignkey to a compute integer value that won't open up any holes. Brush up on your sql injection!

Comment: Still -1 `'$someint'` does the same as `$someint` in MySQL. The latter needs extra code on top(or instead of) of the usual mysql_real_escape_string(), the former does not.

Comment: The foreignkey comes from a query inside the system, where only autoincremented values are stored. So it does not really matter.

Comment: @all: in MySQL `select * from tablea where x = '11'` is the same as `select * from tablea where x = 11` so there is never a good reason to omit the quotes.