# Problem with disappearing value when query is run

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I Can´t get INSERT to work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816327/i-cant-get-insert-to-work)

I have been banging my head to the wall with this:

1. get the POST values to array..
2. Select the foreign key..
3. Some other INSERT-operations

```
$lockdates = "LOCK TABLES dates WRITE'"; 
$lockresult2= mysql_query($lockdates);                          
$pickassssult= (int)$pickassssult;
$uservalues[5]= (int)$uservalues[5];
if (is_int($uservalues)) {
  echo "is integer\n";
} else {
  echo "is not an integer\n";
}
var_dump(is_int($pickassssult));                            

$insertdates = "INSERT INTO dates (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate
                 , maintenance_period, expiration_date) 
                VALUES 
                  ('$pickassssult','$uservalues[1]','$uservalues[4]'
                  ,'$uservalues[5]','$uservalues[3]')";
$upsdasult = mysql_query($insertdates);
echo $insertdates;

if (!$upsdasult) {
  die(mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n");
}

//UNLOCK TABLES
$unlockresult=mysql_query($unlockasset);
```

All the values are in the correct format before the insert and $foreignkey is in correct format. (I have echoed the values before the insert statement).

This is what I get when I echo the query:

```
INSERT INTO dates 
  (asid,acq_date, serv_guaranteedate, maintenance_period, expiration_date) 
VALUES 
  ('47','2008-01-29','2050-03-07','34','2069-12-22')
```

and this is the warning I get:

> **Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in....**

I have checked that the values meet the requirements of the table (INT(11),DATE,DATE,INT(3),DATE) and the PK is autoincremented. As far as I understand the FK-value disappears when the actual command is run and I do not understand why...